# How can I wrap my edit method in a using statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I wrap a portion of my edit method in a using statement?  I tried doing something like this:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<Student> student;
        using( var stdnt=new Student)
        var std = stdnt
            .Include(s => s.Courses)

            .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
            .Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
            .Single();

        PopulateAssignedenrolledData(student, id);             
        PopulateCourseDropDownList(student.CourseID);

        return View(student);

     }
```

I am trying this approach because I keep getting error messages about a DataReader already being opened so I researched and most answers suggests wrapping the code in a using statement or converting to a ToList().  I would like to know how to wrap the code in a using statement. Here’s my edit method that I need help with.

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        Student std = db.Students
            .Include(s => s.Courses)

            .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
            .Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
            .Single();

        PopulateAssignedenrolledData(student, id);              
        PopulateCourseDropDownList(student.CourseID);

        return View(student);
    }
```

Comment: What the other people suggested is - find where you are opening the Datareader and put that in a using block.  We can not see from the code you posted where the datareader is being opened and never closed.

Comment: he's using the entity framework; i can almost guarantee there is no explicit datareader calls anywhere in his code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find in your code where the datareader is being opened and put that in a using block like so

```
   using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   { 
        while (dr.Read()) 
        { 
           //read here 
        } 
   }
```

we can't see from your code where it is being opened and never closed. Try stepping through code and see.  In this example I used SqlDataReader,  you would use the using block the same way for any datareader

Comment: Hu Scott.  I have this at the begging of the class: private SchoolInDB db = new SchoolInDB();  Would this be the point where the datareader is being opened?